# Are there any pitfalls associated with using !var in python?

Tags: python

I want to check if a variable has a truthy value; in Python does something like this work effectively to check that? Or is there a different convention?

```
if not var:
  return False
return var * 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a variable is `True` you can check if it is `True` using the following syntax

```
>>> x = True
>>> if x:
...     print 'hey'
...     
hey
```

To check if a variable is `False` the following syntax could be used:

```
>>> x = False
>>> if not x:
...     print 'hey'
...     
hey
```

Note : There is no need to use the `bool()` function in these cases

Comment: After reading your answer I realized my answer is wrong. OP is also use `!` instead of `not` may be you want to add in answer.

Answer (score 2):

`!` is not negation in Python; Python just uses words for common booleans:

`and` (not `&&`)
`or` (not `||`)
`not` (not `!`)

Generally speaking:

- For numbers, nonzero values are truthy, while zero is falsy
- For containers, empty containers are falsy (you can also think of it as being equivalent to the `len` of the container)
- `None` is falsy
- Any class can define a `__bool__` method with its own custom behavior

Answer (score 1):

The biggest pitfall is that so many things in Python evaluate to a boolean value. The documentation contains a complete list of how (builtin) types can be [tested for truth](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). The following all evaluate to false.

- None
- False
- zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
- any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
- any empty mapping, for example, {}.
- instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a
- **nonzero**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.

To make things easier for yourself, try to restrict the return type of your function to one type and denote exceptional cases with exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

A small hint about your example. In some cases (like yours) making a `if True` check is simpler and shorter:

```
if var:
    return var * 2
```

Because all functions return a value in python. That is also important about truth testing. If a method or function do not have a `return` statement, then it returns `None` Above is equivalent of

```
if var:
    return var * 2
return None
```